# Contextual filter "Allow multiple values" is gone

Tags: views, 8

Why can't I see the "More - Allow multiple values" option on my contextual filter product view?

This is my view:
[image]

This is what should appear:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! What has happened since you saw it the last time and now?

Comment: Hi, thank you! Just figured that out, the answer is below.

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason: My site was in maintenance mode and the green message was preventing the block to appear... So it's a matter of css. Super stupid, but it took me a while to figure that out. Might be useful to someone having the same issue.